# Sql Query for multiple table with target value

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this query that will find a specific borrowDetail when i tried value 2 it does return data
[image: it does return data]

from me but when i tried to find the 1 it does not give any data.
[image: no data]

```
SELECT bd.BorrowDetails_ID, b.User_ID, 
        b.Accession_Code, bk.Book_Title, bd.Quantity, b.Date_Borrowed, 
        b.Due_Date, br.Borrower_ID, bd.tb_status
        FROM
        tbl_borrowdetails AS bd
        INNER JOIN
        tbl_borrow AS b ON bd.Borrower_ID = b.Borrow_ID
        INNER JOIN
        tbl_books AS bk ON b.Accession_Code = bk.Accession_Code
        INNER JOIN
        tbl_borrower AS br ON b.Borrower_ID = br.Borrower_ID
                WHERE   bd.BorrowDetails_ID = 21
```

[image: tb_borrow]

[image: tbl_borrowdetails]

[image: tbl_borrower]

[image: tbl_books]

then this is my query builder

[image]

on the borrower table it does have the data that i inserted on the other page, it registered and was distributed too on the other page, but when i call it in this return page, it does not work only the value 2 work,

i have tried to revise the query yet no success. it kept getting NO record found on the

```
// Check if the borrowId parameter is set in the URL
if(isset($_GET['borrowId'])) {
    // Set the session variable after sanitizing it
    $_SESSION['BorrowDetails_ID'] = filter_var($_GET['borrowId'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    // Optionally, you can redirect back to the same page or perform any other action
    header("Location: staff_return_transaction.php");
    exit();
}

// Initialize $bd_Id to an empty string
$bd_Id = $_SESSION['BorrowDetails_ID'];


        // Prepare the SQL statement with a placeholder for the search input
        $sql = "SELECT bd.BorrowDetails_ID, b.User_ID, 
        b.Accession_Code, bk.Book_Title, bd.Quantity, b.Date_Borrowed, 
        b.Due_Date, br.Borrower_ID, bd.tb_status
        FROM
        tbl_borrowdetails AS bd
        INNER JOIN
        tbl_borrow AS b ON bd.Borrower_ID = b.Borrow_ID
        INNER JOIN
        tbl_books AS bk ON b.Accession_Code = bk.Accession_Code
        INNER JOIN
        tbl_borrower AS br ON b.Borrower_ID = br.Borrower_ID
                WHERE   bd.BorrowDetails_ID = $bd_Id";
```

PLease do help me find what is wrong with my query as why it returns a value to me when i try 2 and why it does not return value when i ask for 1

Comment: save us both some time and publish your sample data as text.

Comment: Why, oh why, are you concatenating SQL in 2024? PHP has had parameterised queries forever.

Comment: `// Prepare the SQL statement with a placeholder` The comment says you're using a placeholder, but the code uses variable interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

```
INNER JOIN   tbl_borrow AS b ON bd.Borrower_ID = b.Borrow_ID
```

should be

```
INNER JOIN   tbl_borrow AS b ON bd.Borrower_ID = b.Borrower_ID
```

Comment: it still return no value sir

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE
b.Borrow_ID = 2;
```

i just changeg the target to borrow_ID from borrowDetails, i just found out that my where statement is the one that provides me with the wrong answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).